# Magento 1: Can modify response as XML of wsdl SOAP v2?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2, wsdl

Can get the response of wsdl SOAP v2 as required formate XML?

I Want to require formate XML response.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://my_host/api/v2_soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$sessionId = $proxy->login('tet', 'tet123');
$result = $proxy->ordersExport($sessionId, 33410);
echo htmlentities($proxy->__getLastResponse());
```

I am getting output as below :

```
<Order>
<item xsi:type="ns1:associativeEntity">
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">OrderID</key>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">1234</value>
</item>
<item xsi:type="ns1:associativeEntity">
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">InvoiceNumber</key>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">125465231</value>
</item>
<item xsi:type="ns1:associativeEntity">
<key xsi:type="xsd:string">TransactionReference</key>
<value xsi:nil="true" />
</item>
</Order>
```

Want output as :

```
<Order>
<OrderID>1234</OrderID>
<InvoiceNumber>125465231</InvoiceNumber>
<TransactionReference></TransactionReference>
</Order>
```

Does anyone have an idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

How we see output in xml format ? i can see in object format please guide me?